# View doesn't change after clicking on routerLink to child route angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hey I'm having this problem and I cant seem to figure out what is wrong, basically I have a `routerLink` that goes to a child route, the url changes to the route I want but the view doesn't update to the component that is linked to the child route that is currently active

**app.component.ts**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**html**

```
<div class="wide component">
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <img class="logo" src="../../assets/img/our-work-component-logo.png"><br>
        <h2>Component Elite</h2>
        <h3>Web portal and promotions</h3>

        <p class="short-description">Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <a routerLink="component" class="button orange-button">View More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { OurWorkComponent } from './our-work/our-work.component';
import { ComponentComponent } from './our-work-content/component/component.component'

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'our-work', component: OurWorkComponent,
      children: [
         { path: 'component', component: ComponentComponent }
      ]
  }
];

@ngModule({
  declarations: [
     OurWorkComponent,
     ComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason it's not changing is because of `children` of `OurWorkComponent`

```
children: [
    { path: 'component', component: ComponentComponent }
]
```

This means there should be `<router-outlet>` in `OurWorkComponent`, but I can't see it, just add that in `OurWorkComponent's` `html` and you are good to go.

---

For more details please do read : https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes

Comment: but the our-work page has content on it so if i put the <router-outlet> on the page only the component page will show up and not the our-work page unless i specify another page for the our-work page but then the url will be our-work/our-work how do I not do that?

Comment: Then remove `children` property and simple use `path: 'our-work/component',`

Comment: but I want to have the child route so I want to be on the our-work page then click on another link and then be on the other page but the url says ourwork/newpage

Comment: @A61NN5, just do one thing , create a simple demo of issue on stackblitz , So we can help you better way, or just go through the link I provided in answer , it will clear all your doubts on how to use routings.

Comment: all I need to be able to do is have a page with the url /our-work with the content I want in it and then be able to click a link to another page and the url change to /our-work/newpage

Comment: @A61NN5, I have already gave the solution for that either add `<router-outlet>` or remove children and add path like `path: 'our-work/component'`